# Why won't this php script execute bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts, php

Why am I not able to execute this bash script using php? I have tried `exec()` as well as `shell_exec()`.

index.php

```
<?php
$old = getcwd();
echo $old;
chdir($old);
$message=exec("a.sh");
print_r($message);
?>
```

a.sh

```
#!bin/bash
echo "i am a" > /opt/lampp/htdocs/a.txt
echo "Done"
```

I have tried `chdir` as suggested here, as well as I have checked my `disable_functions` in `php.ini`, it doesn't have anything. I have also checked other questions, but none seem to solve my problem.

Comment: 1. Why don't you give the full path to the script? 2. Why are you doing `chdir($old)` twice? Is that a typo?

Comment: I have tried that too. But echoing `$old` shows the correct path of a.sh. As `index.php` and `a.sh` are in the same dir. `chdir` was there because I copied that from somewhere, then edited the 1st chdir but not the second.

Comment: I have checked it as I mentioned it in my question. @muru

Comment: Alright, what do the apache logs say? Any mention of an error?

Comment: Does `a.sh` have `#!/bin/bash` as the first line? Have you tried `exec("/bin/bash a.sh")`

Comment: @muru I will check the log now.

Comment: @dan08 yes. It is same as I have posted here. bash works normally on terminal. Is /bin/bash required? I will try that too.

Comment: Aha did not see that BUT you need a leading slash before `bin` so it reads `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @muru Checked all logs, doesn't have a single thing related to exec.

Comment: @dan08 This was embarrassing. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be sure that the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is exactly as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Second, be sure that the script is executable using the following command in terminal:

```
chmod +x /path/to/a.sh
```

And third, you must to use the full path for the bash script, or in your case, you can use:

```
$message=exec("$old/a.sh");
```

And, as an aside note, the following two commands from your php script have no sense:

```
$old = getcwd();
chdir($old);
```

They are equivalent with `chdir(getcwd())`, which change the current directory to ...the current directory, so in fact, nothing happens.

Comment: @OptimusPrime Well, check again, you said in your Q that your bash script starts with `#!bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/bash` as I said which obviously are not the same

Comment: Sorry about previous comment. I did not see that clearly. I have made the file executable. But it still does not write that file `a.txt`. What else may be the problem?

Comment: Permissions problem, plenty of info on this site and around the web.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Yes, I realize they have no effect. But I just copied that from web, and was trying them if they could solve the problem.

Comment: @dan08 Yes, I changed the permissions and it worked. You were right again.

Comment: @OptimusPrime Check if [the user who execute the php script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771586/how-to-check-what-user-php-is-running-as) has [write permissions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm) to `/opt/lampp/htdocs`.